# apk name must with .apk error Google Play publishing error?

Tags: android, google-play

I am getting an error while publishing my apk to **Google Play**. 
I have created release apk and while uploading it to playstore, it says "**apk file name must ends with .apk**" while my apk name is ending with .apk
I don't understand what this issue is about?

Comment: Make sure to read the error description... and that your "apk" file ends in `.apk`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty likely you are making a subtle mistake somewhere, but your apk does not end with ".apk" for the filename

- Are you maybe using a keyboard from a different country so the ".apk" is not using the ASCII characters, but instead uses another character that looks similar
- did you maybe add a space at the end?
- are you making a mistake like copying it into a zip or other compressed format and your file manager hides the extension?

Please copy and paste a listing of a directory with your APK file (using `ls` on Mac/Linux or `dir` on Windows) into the question, then people are more likely to be able to spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks alot for your cooperation, But  I have solved the issue. Virus was affecting my files. after creation of apk, apk file currupted due to virus, SO i was unable to upload.